# Sufficient condition for $\lim _{x \rightarrow 2} f(x)=a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Le $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Assume we have $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(2- \frac{1}{n})= a$

Question 1) Can I interpret that as  $\lim _{x \rightarrow 2^-} f(x)=a$. If not, why?

Question 2) If we additionally assume that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(2 + \frac{1}{n})= a$, can I then conclude that $\lim _{x \rightarrow 2} f(x)=a$ ?

Comment: You cannot conclude either. You only know what $f$ is doing at countable points. It could do all kinds of bizarre things between $2-\frac{1}{n}$ and $2-\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Try a function such as $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{2-x}\pi)$.

Comment: definition of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-} f(x)$ involves something is true for any sequence that converge to $2$ from left side.. How do you think condition on just one sequence $(2-1/n)$ that converge to $2$ from left side can conclude about all sequences?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why must $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @VaradMahashabde The usual convention is that $n$ stands for the indexing variable of a *sequence* which means it has to be a natural number.

Comment: @bjorn93 but isn't $\lim_{h\to\infty} f(2-\frac{1}{h}) = a$ completely equivalent?

Comment: @VaradMahashabde No. We're given a sequence: $f(2-1/1),f(2-1/2),f(2-1/3),f(2-1/4),\dots,f(2-1/n),\dots$

Comment: @bjorn93 Sorry to have bothered you , but really the question should have said so in the text rather than the tag

Answer (score 2):

Take the function

$$f(x)=a \text{ if } x\in \Bbb Q$$ and
$$f(x)=a+1  \text{ otherwise}$$
then

for every $n>0$

$$f(2-\frac 1n)=f(2+\frac 1n)=a$$
but $$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$$ does not exist since
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(2-\frac{\pi}{n})=a+1\ne a$$

Comment: But as $n\rightarrow \infty$, n could take any value along the way. Infinity is neither rational nor irrational!

Comment: That can't be because we typically use $n \in \mathbb{Z}$!!! And it doesn't make sense to insist that any variable approaching $\infty$ do so with integral values!! $\pi \cdot n > n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: I do not disagree that $n>0$, but there are far more large irrational values than large rational or integer values, and $n$ should be free to approach infinity while taking any value, including irrationals. (As we approach getting sent to chat by a mod, my sentences make less and less sense)

Comment: When we write $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$, it means that $n$ goes to infinity but stays in $\Bbb N$. If you don't understand this, i can do nothing for you. you can downvote.

Comment: I shall not downvote, but why? Is it in a definition?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Let $b$ be a number different from $a$ and define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}a&\text{ if }x=2\pm\frac1n\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N\\b&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then you both have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left((2+\frac1n\right)=a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left((2-\frac1n\right)=a$. However, the limit $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)$ doesn't exist.